# skipping checkout in azuredevops clasic editoor when you have 2 agents on build pipeline

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

So I have a build pipeline with 2 agents. Long story short I want the first agent who is doing the first task to skip the checkout because it is wasting too much time doing so.

I tried using `agent.source.skip = true` on variable or assigned this to the agent capabilities, but the down side is that is skipping all the checkout (Skip sync source for repository), not just the first one which I need it to be skipped.

TL&DR: how I stop just 1 checkout and not all of them in my build pipeline?

Answer (score 0):

In the classic editor the "Get Sources" settings is for all the jobs, so if you configured there to skip the checkout it will be skipped in both jobs/agents.

So, you can skip the Get Sources and implement `git clone` in your second job, or just migrate to YAML pipeline.

Comment: Is hard to implement the yaml pipeline because all the pipelines we have are in classic editor, I know the yaml pipeline is better but I'm not there .

Can you please explain to me how to use git clone in the second job ?

I understand that checking in the Don't synch sources box and putting the variable agent.source.skip=true will result in stoping all the jobs checkout. but i still need to have 1 checkout in 1 job :(

Comment: just run git clone command in the beginning of the job...

Comment: I m not using git commands in my build is mostly vsts stuff. what I seen that is working is putting in variable section the agent.source.skip = true but is stopping both agents how can I define there to stop the first agent? i tried putting Default( my agent name ) in that section or Default.source.skip = true is not working :( do you please have any idea about this workaround? thank you in advance

Comment: as i said, you can't. when you putting agent.source.skip = true it will skip both, you can't change it. the workaround it was I suggested - you need to do the "vsts stuff" and implement the git clone in the second job.

Comment: I understand the only solution is a git clone in the second job, but I don't know how to do that, can you please provide me with an example or a tutorial of how to do that. thank you

Comment: add a command line task that run `git clone repo-url`